# Posting JSON in Ruby with HTTParty Returns invalid_request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

It seems that my post is reaching the host, however it may be formatted incorrectly? Not coming in as JSON?

The host's result is presenting me with an error Code: ***invalid_request*
*Message: Validation failed on the request.***

Host Docs:

> This means that Automatic Ordering didn't have enough information to
>   place the order. This almost always occurs because you haven't fully
>   filled out your Amazon account information on your Automatic Ordering
>   section.

My error result includes the following:

```
{
  "_type": "error",
  "_request_id": "5623dcc59ca1bb1e76000a9f",
  "code": "invalid_request",
  "message": "Validation failed on the request.",
  "data": {
    "validator_errors": [
      {
        "path": "retailer_credentials.password",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'retailer_credentials.password' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "retailer_credentials.email",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'retailer_credentials.email' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_method",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_method' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "is_gift",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'is_gift' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.phone_number",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.phone_number' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.country",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.country' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.city",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.city' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.zip_code",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.zip_code' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.address_line1",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.address_line1' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.last_name",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.last_name' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "shipping_address.first_name",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'shipping_address.first_name' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "retailer",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'retailer' field."
      },
      {
        "path": "client_token",
        "message": "'undefined' is not a permitted value for 'client_token' field."
      },
      {
        "value": [],
        "path": "products",
        "message": "'' is not a permitted value for 'products' field."
      }
    ]
  },
  "host": "zincapi-1",
  "offers_urls": [],
  "screenshot_urls": [],
  "_created_at": "2015-10-18T17:54:13.416Z"
}
```

My code is in the index view as:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>IF name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
<% @ifs.each do |t| %>

<!-- Update Each cur_count -->

  <%
  require 'json'
  require 'HTTParty'


  zincUrl = 'https://api.zinc.io/v0/order'
  @ZincResult=HTTParty.post(zincUrl,
    :body => [{
      :client_token => "XXXXXXXX",
  :retailer => "amazon",
  :products => [{"product_id" => ""+t.item+"", "quantity" => 1,
  "seller_selection_criteria" => [
      {
        "condition_in" => ["New"],
        "international" => false,
        "max_shipping_days" => 10
      }
    ]
    }],
  :max_price => 2000,
  :shipping_address => {
  "first_name" => "name",
  "last_name" => "name",
  "address_line1" => "address",
  "address_line2" => "",
  "zip_code" => "94133",
  "city" => "San Francisco",
  "state" => "CA",
  "country" => "US",
  "phone_number" => "number"
  },
  :is_gift => true,
  :gift_message => "present",
  :shipping_method => "cheapest",
  :payment_method => {
  "name_on_card" => "name",
  "number" => "XXXXXXXX",
  "security_code" => "XXX",
  "expiration_month" => "XX",
  "expiration_year" => "XXXX",
  "use_gift" => false
  },
  :billing_address => {
  "first_name" => "name",
  "last_name" => "name",
  "address_line1" => "address",
  "address_line2" => "",
  "zip_code" => "94133",
  "city" => "San Francisco",
  "state" => "CA",
  "country" => "US",
  "phone_number" => "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  :retailer_credentials => {
  "email" => "email",
  "password" => "password"
  },
  :webhooks => {
  "order_placed" => "http://mywebsite.com/zinc/order_placed",
  "order_failed" => "http://mywebsite.com/zinc/order_failed",
  "tracking_obtained" => "http://mywebsite.com/zinc/tracking_obtained"
  },
  :client_notes => {
  "our_internal_order_id" => "Order_"+t.item+"",
  }
  }].to_json,

    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )

  %>

  <%puts "end of Zinc if loop"%>

  <%puts @ZincResult%>

<tr>
  <td><%= t.name %>  </td>
  <td><%= t.item %></td>
  <td><%= t.key %></td>
  <td><%= t.count %></td>
  <td><%= t.cur_count %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'show', if_path(t) %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_if_path(t.id) %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'delete', ifs_delete_path(:id =>t.id)%></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you doing an API call in your view? Thats the last place you should ever put an API call.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @ThomasRoss and Max I'm trying to call the 'https://api.zinc.io/v0/order' API with the above body. I can do it in Python, but now trying to get it working on Ruby. I've now put it in a controller as a method. However, I'm still getting the above error when calling the method. Thank you very much for taking a look, I've been banging my head against this for awhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Zinc Docs](https://zinc.io/docs/#order-api) you should send json object in body but you are sending json array. To send JSON Object, you should start your body with curly braces "{}" and not square brackets "[]"

```
@ZincResult=HTTParty.post(zincUrl,
    :body => {.........}.to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```